# I am very new to programming. I wrote this Ruby script and realized that there is no space between the string and variable

Tags: ruby

```
character_name = "John"
character_age = "35"
puts ( "There was a dude named" + character_name )
puts ( "he was"  + character_age + "years old." )
puts ( "He really liked the name" +  character_name )
puts ( "but didnt like being" +  character_age +  "." )
```

[The output of the program given up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UysFy.png)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your question is how to put the spaces in. The answer is to... put the spaces in! :)

```
character_name = "John"
character_age = "35"
puts ( "There was a dude named " + character_name )
puts ( "he was "  + character_age + " years old." )
puts ( "He really liked the name " +  character_name )
puts ( "but didnt like being " +  character_age +  "." )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation and format string as you need

```
character_name = "John"
character_age = 35

puts "There was a dude named #{character_name}"
puts "he was #{character_age} years old."
puts "He really liked the name #{character_name}"
puts "but didnt like being #{character_age}."
```

It allows you to make some sort of templates

It is clearer, better readable than string concatenation. It also doesn't produce unnecessary intermediate string objects